# curve_fit() with fourier series poorly

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

First I use "Curve Fitting Tool" in Matlab2016b to fit a signal, when number of terms is 4 ,the fourier series can fit the observe signal perfectly.

Then I try to write python code achieve it ,but it cannot fit the signal well. So can you help me ?

```
import math,os,numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fourier(x,*a):
# maybe a = [ a0 , w , a1 , b1 , a2 , b2 ....]
    ret = a[0]
    w   = a[1]
    deg = int(len(a)/2-1)
    
    for i in range(1,deg+1):
        ret += a[2*i] * np.cos(i*w*x) + a[2*i+1] * np.sin(i*w*x)
    return ret

phase1_gtc202301 = np.loadtxt('XSM-20230111233742-20230209154234-0.1Hz.txt')[:,11]

dt = 1/0.1/60/60/24                         # DAY
N  = 247679
t  = np.linspace(dt,N*dt,N)

[A,B] = curve_fit(fourier,t,phase1_gtc202301,[0.2]*8,absolute_sigma=True)
phasefit = fourier(t,*A)

plt.plot(t,phase1_gtc202301,t,phasefit)
```

[image][image]

fit a Fourier series to a data

Comment: Maybe you should try different starting points? There should be an option in curvefit. Say randomize it.

Comment: @Emil yes ,when i randomize the point using np.random.rand(10),sometimes it runs well, sometimes it is poor...

Comment: I suggest you either find the range which works well for most of the cases, or run a loop to run it several times with random value and choose the best one with largest R^2. Maybe there is another way, but who knows...